# Distance between the rotated label and the line in map composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, rotate

When trying to print rotated map in composer manager labels are shifted:

[image: screenshot of map composer 2.18.4]

In map canvas everything is OK!

I need to save again my layer in project projection for avoid this offset.

**It was tested in version 2.6 there were no offset:**

[image: screenshot of map composer 2.6]

[here](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16897) is my loaded files: the line and point vector layers with their styles, project file.

The "trick" with adding the map object in print composer, rotate the map canvas, then rotate the map object also in the composer is very unconvinient for me, because I use atlas generation and creating new composer is unnecessary.
When I choose the map that I want to print in composer atlas list menu, I have already defined rotation angle value (calculated from projection formula), 
and even if I manually set it to 0 and then my angle again, there is still offset.

Is it possible to get rid of this distance without creation new composer?

Some ideas?)